# More elegant way to write this ActiveRecord query?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I had the following function. It worked, but I don't like the way it looked.

```
# in user.rb
def awarded_requests
  Request.joins('JOIN application ON application.request_id = request.id').where('accepted = true AND application.user_id = ?', self.id)
end
```

Then I refactored it to something that's clearly an improvement, but probably not simplest possible form:

```
def awarded_requests
  Request.find(self.applications.accepted.map(&:request_id))
end
```

Can this be simplified further?

Comment: Please provide your model relations so we know how your tables relate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up has many relationship, you can filter out those requests by merging a scope.

```
class User
  has_many :applications

  def awarded_requests
    Request.joins(:applications).merge(applications.accepted)
  end
end
```

Note that `applications.accepted` is not an array of records but a scope. This is how Active Record represents a part of SQL query internally, therefore it can smartly combine a few of them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `Request.scoped.merge(applications.accepted)` didn't work because it came through missing the join, but that code led me to an answer that worked. I ended up doing `Request.joins(:applications).merge(applications.accepted)`. If you change your answer to match that, I'll accept it.

Comment: I looked up this in one of my projects, the join must be somewhere in default scope then.